Vector layer access issue when upgrading GeoServer
Yesterday, I switched the version of GeoServer from 2.19.2 to 2.25.3 and found some vector layer access errors. The request was rejected because the URL contained a potentially malicious String '%25', no solution has been found

As from version 2.25.0 of Geoserver the spring security firewall is enabled by default according to the release notes. If you have percent sign in resources URL:s it may be blocked.
Solution is found at https://docs.geoserver.org/2.25.x/en/user/production/config.html#production-config-spring-firewall
Copied from there:

GeoServer defaults to using Spring Security’s StrictHttpFirewall to
help improve protection against potentially malicious requests.
However, some users will need to disable the StrictHttpFirewall if the
names of GeoServer resources (workspaces, layers, styles, etc.) in URL
paths need to contain encoded percent, encoded period or decoded or
encoded semicolon characters. The GEOSERVER_USE_STRICT_FIREWALL
property can be set to false either via Java system property, command
line argument (-D), environment variable or web.xml init parameter to
use the more lenient DefaultHttpFirewall.

